# Google Tag Manager - Custom Javascript Variable returns undefined, stopping trigger

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Im new to GTM and trying to create a custom javascript variable to return whether or not an action/event was in the footer or main body of the website. I want to use it to differentiate triggers in GTM like link clicks/form submit, etc.

Custom javascript variable code:

```
function() {
 var e = {{Form Element}};
 return e[0].indexOf("#footer");
}
```

On form submit shows up in the data layer as undefined:
[image: Data layer Sceenshot]

But if I take off the `.indexOf("#footer")` and try

```
function() {
 var e = {{Form Element}};
 return e[0];
}
```

It shows in the data layer as:
[image: Data layer screenshot 2]

So im not sure why `.indexOf()` wasn't working but then If I try and change my trigger to us `contains "#footer"` logic in GTM it doesnt match.
[image: Failed trigger screenshot]

Im probably doing multiple things wrong. But I dont even know enough about GTM to know what question to ask.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e[0]` is not a string, but an `HTMLInputElement`. The conversion to a string is only done by the UI there, and, as far as I can tell, is not anything standard.

If you want to check whether an element is contained in the subtree of another, use [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains):

```js
function() {
 var e = {{Form Element}};
 return document.getElementById('footer').contains(e);
}
```

You might have to replace `'footer'` with `'footer-router'` or something like that, since I don't actually see `#footer` by itself in the element's path.

I also changed `e[0]` to just `e`, since the first input element of a form and the form itself would be in the same subtree, even if it's the form itself that has ID `footer`.

Comment: Thank you! It did need to be `.contains(e[0])` rather than just `.contains(e)` to not return undefined, but so helpful to know its a HTMLInputElement rather than a string.